# Calculating bytes of code

Tags: parsing, perl

I am new to Perl and I wrote this Perl script to calculate bytes of code and lines of code in a directory. I want to know if there are any improvements that can be made to it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# codestats.pl
# A perl script to calculate the number of lines of code in a project
# and what type of lines those code are, such as comments, code, or
# newlines. This script is specific to C/C++, but it should work with any
# language that has the same commenting scheme, so it should probably work
# with java too.
#
# Henry J Schmale
# April 30, 2015

use strict;
use warnings;

my @srcext = ("*.cpp", "*.c", "*.h", "*.hpp", "*.ino", "*.cxx", "*.cc");

my $commLines = 0; # Lines that start with a comment symbol
my $bothLines = 0; # Lines that have a comment and code
my $newLines  = 0; # Lines that are just whitespace
my $codeLines = 0; # Lines of code - lines that don't fit in another space
my $totLines  = 0; # Total lines of code
my $srcBytes  = 0; # Total Number of bytes in src code
my $fCount    = 0; # Number of files read

my $files;
for($a = 0; $a < scalar(@srcext); $a++){
    $files .= `find . -name "$srcext[$a]"`;
}
my @inputs = split("\n", $files);
for($a = 0; $a < scalar(@inputs); $a++){
    my $prev = $totLines;
    countLines($inputs[$a]);
    printf("Read %d ln. In %s\n", $totLines - $prev, $inputs[$a]);
    $fCount++;
}
printResults();

# Count the lines in the given file
# The first param is the file to open for counting
sub countLines{
    my ($srcfile) = @_;
    open(FILE, "<$srcfile") or die "Couldn't open file: $!\n";
    my @lines = <FILE>;
    for($b = 0; $b < scalar(@lines); $b++){
        $srcBytes += length($lines[$b]);
        $totLines++;
        if($lines[$b] =~ /^\s$/){ # is only whitespace ==> newLine
            $newLines++;
            next;
        }
        if(($lines[$b] =~ /^\s*\/\//) || # comments only lines
           ($lines[$b] =~ /^\s*\/\*/) ||
           ($lines[$b] =~ /^\s*\*/)){
            $commLines++;
            next;
        }
        # code + comments
        if(($lines[$b] =~ /\/\//) ||
           ($lines[$b] =~ /\/\*.*\*\//)){
            $bothLines++;
            next;
        }
        $codeLines++;
    }
    close FILE;
}

sub calcPercent{
    return ($_[0] / $_[1]) * 100.0;
}

sub printResults{
    # print out the results
    printf("Read %d Files\n", $fCount);
    printf("Average Lines Per File: %d\n", $totLines / $fCount);
    printf("Code    : %09d ln. %06.3f", $codeLines, calcPercent($codeLines, $totLines));
    print "%\n";
    printf("Comment : %09d ln. %06.3f", $commLines, calcPercent($commLines, $totLines));
    print "%\n";
    printf("Blank   : %09d ln. %06.3f", $newLines,  calcPercent($newLines,  $totLines));
    print "%\n";
    printf("Both    : %09d ln. %06.3f", $bothLines, calcPercent($bothLines, $totLines));
    print "%\n";
    printf("Total   : %09d ln.\n", $totLines);
    printf("CodeSize: %09d bytes\n", $srcBytes);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy to write very ugly Perl code,
but this is pretty nicely written, so congrats.

[Using barewords for file handles like this is discouraged](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/perl/FIO00-PL.+Do+not+use+bareword+file+handles):

> ```
> open(FILE, "<$srcfile") or die "Couldn't open file: $!\n";
> my @lines = <FILE>;
> # ...
> close FILE;
> ```

The recommended way:

```
open(my $fh, "<$srcfile") or die "Couldn't open file: $!\n";
my @lines = <$fh>;
# ...
close $fh;
```

Some simplifications are possible.
For example instead of this:

> ```
> my @srcext = ("*.cpp", "*.c");
> ```

I find this way a lot easier to type:

```
my @srcext = qw/*.cpp *.c/;
```

Another, bigger simplification is in the loops.
Instead of this:

> ```
> my @lines = <FILE>;
> for($b = 0; $b < scalar(@lines); $b++){
>     $srcBytes += length($lines[$b]);
>     $totLines++;
>     if($lines[$b] =~ /^\s$/){ # is only whitespace ==> newLine
>         $newLines++;
>         next;
>     }
>     if(($lines[$b] =~ /^\s*\/\//) || # comments only lines
>        ($lines[$b] =~ /^\s*\/\*/) ||
>        ($lines[$b] =~ /^\s*\*/)){
> ```

You can iterate using `for (<$fh>) { ... }`,
and instead of `$lines[$b]`, benefit from the auto-variable `$_`,
which can be omitted from `$lines[$b] =~ /.../` statements,
like this:

```
for (<$fh>) {
    $srcBytes += length($_);
    $totLines++;
    if(/^\s$/){ # is only whitespace ==> newLine
        $newLines++;
        next;
    }
    if(/^\s*\/\// || # comments only lines
       /^\s*\/\*/ ||
       /^\s*\*/){
```

Answer (score 5):

### Regexes

Your `/^\s$/` regex, intended to count the number of "blank" lines, only matches lines that are completely empty or that contain just a space or tab.  If there are two spaces, it won't match.

Use `m!regex!` (or any other convenient delimiter) instead of `/regex/` when your regex itself contains slashes, to avoid "leaning toothpick syndrome".

Of course, crude regex matching is not completely accurate. If a `//` appears within a literal string, for example, it would be misinterpreted as the start of a comment. Conversely, in multi-line `/* comments */`, only the first and last line are being recognized as comments.

### `File::Find`

Instead of shelling out to `find`, use [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html).

### Data-directed programming

There is a proliferation of global variables, which `countLines()` manipulates as a side-effect, and which `printResults()` consumes implicitly.  I recommend putting them in some kind of data structure so that they can be passed around easily.  For example, using subtraction in

> ```
> my $prev = $totLines;
> countLines($inputs[$a]);
> printf("Read %d ln. In %s\n", $totLines - $prev;
> ```

to retrieve information about the most recently processed file feels like a bit of a hack.

The `countLines()` function is a bit tedious, with multiple `if` statements.  It would be more elegant to declare, up front, the regexes for all of the types of lines you are interested in.  [This technique](//stackoverflow.com/a/1849356/1157100) is useful for counting the number of times a regex matches.

### Printing

If you omit the parentheses when calling `print`, then omit them when calling `printf` as well.

Use `printf` to print the percent signs as well.  The trick is to use `%%` to represent a literal percent character.

### Suggested solution

```
use File::Find;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @src_exts = qw(.cpp .c .h .hpp .ino .cxx .cc);

my %categories = (
  'Comment' => qr!^\s*(?://|/\*|\*/\s*$)!, # Lines that start with a comment symbol
  'Blank'   => qr!^\s*$!,                  # Lines that are just whitespace
  'Both'    => qr!\S.*/[/*].*|\*/.*\S.*/!, # Lines that have a comment and code
  'Bytes'   => qr!.!s,                     # Total bytes
  'Total'   => qr!^!,                      # Total lines
);

sub count_lines {
    my ($srcfile) = @_;
    my %stats = map { $_ => 0 } keys %categories;
    open FILE, '<', $srcfile or die "Could not open file $srcfile: $!";
    for my $line (<FILE>) {
        while (my ($cat, $regex) = each %categories) {
            $stats{$cat} += scalar(() = $line =~ m/$regex/g);
        }
    }
    close FILE;
    return \%stats;
}

sub add_stats {
    my $sum = { %{shift()} };
    for my $file_stats (@_) {
        for my $cat (keys $file_stats) {
            $sum->{$cat} += $file_stats->{$cat};
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}

sub percent {
    return (shift() / shift()) * 100.0;
}

sub print_results {
    my (@file_stats) = @_;
    my $stats = add_stats(@file_stats);
    my $total_lines = $stats->{'Total'};
    my $code_lines = $total_lines - $stats->{'Comment'} - $stats->{'Blank'};

    printf "Read %d Files\n", scalar @file_stats;
    printf "Average Lines Per File: %d\n", $stats->{'Total'} / scalar @file_stats;
    printf "Code    : %9d ln. %6.3f%%\n", $code_lines,         percent($code_lines,         $total_lines);
    printf "Comment : %9d ln. %6.3f%%\n", $stats->{'Comment'}, percent($stats->{'Comment'}, $total_lines);
    printf "Blank   : %9d ln. %6.3f%%\n", $stats->{'Blank'},   percent($stats->{'Blank'},   $total_lines);
    printf "Both    : %9d ln. %6.3f%%\n", $stats->{'Both'},    percent($stats->{'Both'},    $total_lines);
    printf "Total   : %9d ln.\n", $total_lines;
    printf "CodeSize: %9d bytes\n", $stats->{'Bytes'};
}

my @stats = ();
File::Find::find({ wanted => sub {
    for my $ext (@src_exts) {
        if (/\Q$ext\E$/) {
            my $file_stats = count_lines($_);
            printf("Read %d ln. In %s\n", $file_stats->{'Total'}, $_);
            push @stats, $file_stats;
        }
    }
}}, '.');
print_results(@stats);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll focus on important issues regarding your code,

Don't use `$a` and `$b` global variables as these are used by `sort()` and are exempt from strict check, nor it is recommended to use them as lexical (`my`) variables.

C style `for` loops can be error prone, and are more verbose than perl for(each), ie.

```
for my $i (0 .. $#srcext) {
    $files .= `find . -name "$srcext[$i]"`;
}
```

`split()` uses regex as delimiter even when you pass the string to it which is good to remember when using regex metachars, thus

```
my @inputs = split(/\n/, $files);
```

Globtypes are discouraged to use as filehandles as they are package globals and should be localized prior to usage (ie. `local *FILE`).
Also three argument `open()` is better for security reasons, thus

```
open(my $file, "<", $srcfile) or die "$! $srcfile\n";
```

Since you're processing file line by line, it's better to read from it in the same way instead of reading whole file into memory at once (`@lines`), thus

```
while (my $line = <$file>) { .. }
```